# Why I can't dynamically set CPU to execute task in Ada?

Tags: parallel-processing, task, cpu, ada, multitasking

I am trying to make an array of Integers, which is accessed inside the task.
`with CPU=>CPUs(1)` doesn't work, as doesn't work any expression at all. 
Plain integers work fine, though.

```
procedure Lab1 is
n: Integer:=222;
 CPUs: array (1..3) of Integer := (1, 1, 1);
 pri:  array (1..3) of  Integer := (1, 5, 10);

 task T3
   with CPU=>1+1
 is
            pragma Priority(pri(1));
            pragma Task_Name ("T3");
         end T3; 

         task body T3 is
         int1:Integer:=generate_random_number(4)+n;
```

I read [that](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-5-3.html) it should be possible.

> The expression giving the processor for a task can be dynamic.

Adding `use System.Multiprocessors.CPU_Range;` gives me:

> Lab1.ada:20:05: "System" is not visible Lab1.ada:20:05: non-visible
>   declaration at system.ads:37 Lab1.ada:22:11: warning: file name does
>   not match unit name, should be "lab1.adb" Lab1.ada:30:14: operator for
>   type "System.Multiprocessors.CPU_Range" is not directly visible
>   Lab1.ada:30:14: use clause would make operation legal

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it.

```
with System.Multiprocessors;
use System.Multiprocessors;

procedure Lab1 is
n: Integer:=222;
CPUs: array (1..3) of CPU_Range := (1, 1, 1);
pri:  array (1..3) of  Integer := (1, 5, 10);


task T3 
  with CPU=>CPUs(1)
is
```